# Test generic type parameter for interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have a generic method (see code below) and want to perform some action if T is a particular interface.
Obviously I could just do a `typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(IFoo)` but reflection is comparatively slow so I want to avoid it if possible.

Now, I know I can't have another method with the a constraint because I'd get the ambiguous method error otherwise I'd just do that.

Is there a way of doing what I want?
Does the fact that I want to do this point to some architectural problem?

```
public T Load<T>(string name)
{
    T result = LoadFromName<T>(name);

    if(T is IFoo) // Obviously doesn't work as T is a type, not a variable
        (result as IFoo).FooMethod();

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But you *have* got a variable - `result`! What's wrong with

```
var asFoo = result as IFoo;
if (asFoo != null)
    asFoo.FooMethod();
```